# paramiko: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, ssh, eof, paramiko

Here's the python code:

```
import os
import paramiko
import sys

def get_private_key():
    # or choose the location and the private key file on your client
    private_key_file = os.path.expanduser("/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa")
    return paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(private_key_file, password='')


def get_ssh(myusername, myhostname, myport):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    #ssh.connect(myhostname, username=myusername, port=myport, pkey = private_key)
    ssh.connect(myhostname, username=myusername, port=myport)
    return ssh

def block_exec(ssh, command):
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
    exit_status = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
    print command, exit_status
    print "stderr is %s" % stderr
    return

def clear_bw_config2(ssh, interface):
    block_exec(ssh, "sudo tc qdisc del dev %s root" % interface)
    block_exec(ssh, "sudo tc qdisc del dev %s ingress" % interface)
    block_exec(ssh, "sudo tc class del dev %s root" % interface)
    block_exec(ssh, "sudo tc filter del dev %s root" % interface)



def exec_bw_config2(ssh, interface, bandwidth, ip, subnetmasklength, delay):
    clear_bw_config2(ssh, interface)
    # create a qdisc (queuing discipline), 12 is default class
    cmd1 = "sudo tc qdisc add dev %s root handle 1: htb default 12" % interface
    print cmd1
    block_exec(ssh, cmd1)

    # define the performance for default class
    cmd2 = "sudo tc class add dev %s parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate %dmbps ceil %dmbps" % (interface, bandwidth, 2*bandwidth )
    print cmd2

    block_exec(ssh, cmd2)


    filter_cmd = "sudo tc filter add dev %s protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst %s/%d flowid 1:1" % (interface, ip, subnetmasklength)
    print filter_cmd
    block_exec(ssh, filter_cmd)

    #delay_cmd = "sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1: handle 1: netem delay %dms" %(delay)
    delay_cmd="sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem %dms" %delay
    print delay_cmd
    block_exec(ssh, delay_cmd)


def main():
    myhosts = ["10.0.1.192", "10.0.1.191", "10.0.1.190"]
    username="ubuntu"
    port=22
    #key = get_private_key()
    for host in myhosts:
        ssh = get_ssh(username, host, port)
        clear_bw_config2(ssh, "eth0")
        del_cmd="sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 root"
        block_exec(ssh, del_cmd)
        exec_bw_config2(ssh, "eth0", int(sys.argv[1]) , "10.0.1.0", 24, int(sys.argv[2]))

    # iterate over hosts here
    # for everyhost,
    # 1. create ssh connection
    # 2. run the exec_bw_config with params
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am running the script like this:

```
python network_controller_vm.py 100 10
```

And here's the errors I receive:

```
sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 ingress 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc class del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

sudo tc filter del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
We have an error talking to the kernel

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 ingress 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc class del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

sudo tc filter del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
We have an error talking to the kernel

sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 12
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 12 0

sudo tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbps ceil 200mbps
sudo tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbps ceil 200mbps 0

sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.0.1.0/24 flowid 1:1
sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.0.1.0/24 flowid 1:1 0

sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem 10ms
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem 10ms 1
What is "10ms"?
Usage: ... netem [ limit PACKETS ] 
                 [ delay TIME [ JITTER [CORRELATION]]]
                 [ distribution {uniform|normal|pareto|paretonormal} ]
                 [ corrupt PERCENT [CORRELATION]] 
                 [ duplicate PERCENT [CORRELATION]]
                 [ loss random PERCENT [CORRELATION]]
                 [ loss state P13 [P31 [P32 [P23 P14]]]
                 [ loss gemodel PERCENT [R [1-H [1-K]]]
                 [ ecn ]
                 [ reorder PRECENT [CORRELATION] [ gap DISTANCE ]]
                 [ rate RATE [PACKETOVERHEAD] [CELLSIZE] [CELLOVERHEAD]]

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 ingress 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc class del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

sudo tc filter del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
We have an error talking to the kernel

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 ingress 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc class del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

sudo tc filter del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
We have an error talking to the kernel

sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 12
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 12 0

sudo tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbps ceil 200mbps
sudo tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbps ceil 200mbps 0

sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.0.1.0/24 flowid 1:1
sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.0.1.0/24 flowid 1:1 0

sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem 10ms
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem 10ms 1
What is "10ms"?
Usage: ... netem [ limit PACKETS ] 
                 [ delay TIME [ JITTER [CORRELATION]]]
                 [ distribution {uniform|normal|pareto|paretonormal} ]
                 [ corrupt PERCENT [CORRELATION]] 
                 [ duplicate PERCENT [CORRELATION]]
                 [ loss random PERCENT [CORRELATION]]
                 [ loss state P13 [P31 [P32 [P23 P14]]]
                 [ loss gemodel PERCENT [R [1-H [1-K]]]
                 [ ecn ]
                 [ reorder PRECENT [CORRELATION] [ gap DISTANCE ]]
                 [ rate RATE [PACKETOVERHEAD] [CELLSIZE] [CELLOVERHEAD]]

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 ingress 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc class del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

sudo tc filter del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
We have an error talking to the kernel

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 ingress 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

sudo tc class del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

sudo tc filter del dev eth0 root 2
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
We have an error talking to the kernel

sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 12
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 12 0

sudo tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbps ceil 200mbps
sudo tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbps ceil 200mbps 0

sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.0.1.0/24 flowid 1:1
sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.0.1.0/24 flowid 1:1 0

sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem 10ms
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem 10ms 1
What is "10ms"?
Usage: ... netem [ limit PACKETS ] 
                 [ delay TIME [ JITTER [CORRELATION]]]
                 [ distribution {uniform|normal|pareto|paretonormal} ]
                 [ corrupt PERCENT [CORRELATION]] 
                 [ duplicate PERCENT [CORRELATION]]
                 [ loss random PERCENT [CORRELATION]]
                 [ loss state P13 [P31 [P32 [P23 P14]]]
                 [ loss gemodel PERCENT [R [1-H [1-K]]]
                 [ ecn ]
                 [ reorder PRECENT [CORRELATION] [ gap DISTANCE ]]
                 [ rate RATE [PACKETOVERHEAD] [CELLSIZE] [CELLOVERHEAD]]
```

Comment: You should add  "delay" between netem and 10ms

Comment: Does this help?  https://serverfault.com/questions/616330/debian7-and-tc-qdisc-issue-rtnetlink-answers-no-such-file-or-directory  -- It looks like `tc` is not properly configured.  I don't think this is a Python/Anaconda problem.